# Transferring photos between iPhones keeping metadata

Tags: iphone, photos, data-transfer, ios, file-transfer

I want to transfer all photos from my old iPhone 6 to a new iPhone 7 Plus(both running iOS 10.3.2, if relevant). Since my iCloud is full, I first thought about iTunes, but many photos are shown as blank after backing up the old iPhone and restoring data to the new one via iTunes:

[image]

Then I tried Airdrop, but metadata like locations and time seem to be lost, because the order of photos isn't retained.

Finally I tried [PhotoShare](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bluetooth-photo-share/id326109583?mt=8), but it cannot keep the metadata too.

Please tell me how to transfer photos between two iPhones while keeping their metadata.

Comment: Hey! Were you able to solve this out? I cannot think of a possible way so it would be helpful if you could answer how you did this!

Comment: Could you use Image Capture as an intermediary? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307617/277307