# transfer photos from iPhone to computer **without** importing to Photos

Tags: iphone, high-sierra

Is it possible to transfer photos from iPhone to computer **without** importing to Photos.

I have iPhone5 running iOS 10 (which I don't want to "upgrade" to iOS11).
My Mac is running macOS 10.13.1 with iTunes 12.6.2, but I could also use a computer running Linux.

Previously I had a number of methods of transferring photos, but none of these seem to work any more on High Sierra.

I **DO NOT** want to import into Photos, but retain the photos with their original names, metadata etc.

If all else fails, I could use Dropbox, but transferring 1000s of files on a slow upload link, just so I could download them seems slow and inefficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the Image Capture app. It should allow you to import all your pictures with very little hassle, and comes bundled with macOS.

[image]

Comment: so just to clarify, importing in the context of this app means to copy over the individual image files to the macos system correct? Does that process leave them on the device too or removes them?

Comment: @jxramos Correct. It leaves them by default, but you can delete them from inside the app if you so desire.